# How can I substitute my loop function and understand the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code which allows you to make an entry through InputBox, then based on its ItemType variable will copy the data into the appropriate sheet. I know that I should avoid using ActiveCell and Activate functions, though I don't know how to substitute them. I would be so gratefull if you showed me some examples.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub Data_Entry()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Data
Dim ws0 As Worksheet: Set ws0 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg FG
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg FG")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg RAW
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg RAW")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg Sub-Assy
Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Resale
Dim ws4 As Worksheet: Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Resale")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Conv Resale
Dim ws5 As Worksheet: Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Conv Resale")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg FG PE
Dim ws6 As Worksheet: Set ws6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg FG PE")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg Sub-Assy PE
Dim ws7 As Worksheet: Set ws7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Acrylics
Dim ws8 As Worksheet: Set ws8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Acrylics")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg Raw PE
Dim ws9 As Worksheet: Set ws9 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PE")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg FG PVC
Dim ws10 As Worksheet: Set ws10 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg FG PVC")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg Raw PVC
Dim ws11 As Worksheet: Set ws11 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PVC")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg Sub-Assy PVC
Dim ws12 As Worksheet: Set ws12 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC")



Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim ItemType As String
Dim Issues As String
Dim InventoryValue As String
Dim NextRow


ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

'----------------------------------------------------- Data

NextRow = ws0.Cells(ws0.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

 ws0.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = ItemNumber
 ws0.Range("F" & NextRow).Value = ItemType
 ws0.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = Issues
 ws0.Range("I" & NextRow).Value = InventoryValue

 ws0.Range("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1).Copy
 ws0.Range("A" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'----------------------------------------------------- If statement
'--------------- Mfg FG
If ItemType = "Mfg FG" Then
ws1.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg RAW
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg RAW" Then
ws2.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg Sub-Assy
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg Sub-Assy" Then
ws3.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Resale
ElseIf ItemType = "Resale" Then
ws4.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Conv Resale
ElseIf ItemType = "Conv Resale" Then
ws5.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg FG PE
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg FG PE" Then
ws6.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg Sub-Assy PE
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg Sub-Assy PE" Then
ws7.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Acrylics
ElseIf ItemType = "Acrylics" Then
ws8.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg Raw PE
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg Raw PE" Then
ws9.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg FG PVC
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg FG PVC" Then
ws10.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg Raw PVC
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg Raw PVC" Then
ws11.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
'--------------- Mfg Sub-Assy PVC
ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg Sub-Assy PVC" Then
ws12.Activate
Range("A13").Activate

End If

'------------------------------------------------ Loop
Do

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop

ActiveCell.Value = ItemNumber
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Issues
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = InventoryValue



 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Also, there is a part in my code what I don't understand. I know it finds the last row but what does `("A" & NextRow`)`,("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1)` mean?

```
 NextRow = ws0.Cells(ws0.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


     ws0.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = ItemNumber
     ws0.Range("F" & NextRow).Value = ItemType
     ws0.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = Issues
     ws0.Range("I" & NextRow).Value = InventoryValue

     ws0.Range("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1).Copy
     ws0.Range("A" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this by using a dictionary to 'map' your item types to the relevant sheets. Your code could then be drastically simplified. Have a look at the following. I've tried to explain what chunks are doing in the comments

```
Sub Data_Entry()
    Dim wsDict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NoRow As Long, NextRow As Long
    Dim ItemNumber As String, ItemType As String, Issues As String, InventoryValue As String

    ' Initialise Dictionary, you could use early or late binding - I've used late to avoid adding a reference
    Set wsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With wsDict
        ' Add all item types and relevant sheets to dictionary
        ' .Add Key:=ItemType, Item:=SheetName
        .Add Key:="Mfg FG", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Raw", Item:="ABCX Mfg RAW"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy"
        .Add Key:="Resale", Item:="ABCX Resale"
        .Add Key:="Conv Resale", Item:="ABCX Conv Resale"
        .Add Key:="Mfg FG PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG PE"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE"
        .Add Key:="Acrylics", Item:="ABCX Acrylics"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Raw PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg Raw PE"
        .Add Key:="Mfg FG PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG PVC"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Raw PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg Raw PVC"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC"
        ' .... Rest of your sheets
    End With

    ' Input Boxes althought this may be better handled with a userform instead of 4 separate inputs
    ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
    ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
    Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
    InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

    ' Update your data sheet (let as is)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
         .Range("A" & NextRow).Value2 = ItemNumber
         .Range("F" & NextRow).Value2 = ItemType
         .Range("H" & NextRow).Value2 = Issues
         .Range("I" & NextRow).Value2 = InventoryValue

         .Range("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1).Copy
         .Range("A" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    ' Test if Item Type exists
    If wsDict.exists(ItemType) Then
        ' Test if worksheet exists
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsDict(ItemType))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            With ws
                ' Find last empty row in Column A
                NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                ' If it is less than 13 then set it to 13
                If NoRow < 13 Then NoRow = 13
                ' Add in your data from inputs
                With .Cells(NoRow, "A")
                    .Value2 = ItemNumber
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Issues
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value2 = InventoryValue
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Else
        ' Chuck user out if item doesn't exist
        MsgBox "Item Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

To add in an extra item you just need to add it to the dictionary (`wsDict`)